# Java. Доступ к свойствам объекта из метода этого объекта

Tags: java, методы

При обращении к свойствам объекта из метода этого же объекта получаю ошибку.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Main {
        Main main;
        String string1;
        String string2;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.string1 = "Строка1";
            main.string2 = "Строка2";
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    System.out.println(main.string1);
                    main.metod1();
                }
            });
            frame.add(button);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(100,100);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        public void metod1(){
            System.out.println(main.string2);
        }
    }
```

Почему `string1` печатается, а `string2` нет?

Консоль после нажатия кнопки:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=62581:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Garbuz\IdeaProjects\untitled3\out\production\untitled3" Main
Строка1
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.metod1(Main.java:29)
    at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:19)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: "Почему string1 печатается, а string2 нет" - потому что печатается не ``string1``, а ``main.string1``. Это разные вещи. То же самое со string2.

Answer (score 0):

main.string1 обращается к екз. Main объявленному в методе main.
main.string2 обращается к екз. Main объявленному как поле класса Main

Comment: Почему так происходит? Я обе переменные объявляю одинаково и хочу, чтобы они были полями одного и того же объекта main. Получается у меня их создается два разных? А как сделать, чтобы это был один и тот же объект?

Comment: @Sergey если еще актуально - ты создал две переменные типа Main, а объект положил только в одну из них. Лучше сделать так - в методе main напиши "new Main();". И перенеси все строки из метода в конструктор - public Main(){...};.    Тогда тебе не понадобится хранить экземпляр Main, потому что ты будешь "внутри" экземплеяра. Jframe и и д тоже вынеси в поля класса

Answer (score 0):

Посколько обращение идет из разных мест, то и обращаться надо по разному:

```
public void metod1(){
    System.out.println(string2);
}
```

Comment: А как создать объект класса или поле, являющееся объектом другого класса, чтобы из всех методов класса можно было к нему обратиться?

Comment: В моем коде написано же как обратиться! Вообще, обо всём этом подробно написано в учебниках.

Comment: Мне нужен объект или поле, к которым я смогу обращаться и из main, и из metod1, и из других методов и классов, чтобы я, например, поменял его в main и это изменение было видно отовсюду. Вообще вместо string1 и string2 у меня JFrame и куча других параметров. Этот пример упрощен, но в целом отражает проблему. Собственно задача-то не вывести string2 через metod1, а сделать так, чтобы main.string1 и там и там было одним и тем же полем одного объекта.

Comment: Нужно - делайте. Как делать - подробно написано в каждом учебнике. Это самые азы ООП. И как я написал выше - в моем коде УЖЕ НАПИСАНО КАК ОБРАТИТЬСЯ к полю string1 объекта main из другого метода.